# Fill the holes?

Tags: number-sequence

You have to fill the boxes to make the equation true:

+   +   = 30

Using only <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>5</kbd>, <kbd>7</kbd>, <kbd>9</kbd>, <kbd>11</kbd>, <kbd>13</kbd>, <kbd>15</kbd>.

You can also repeat the numbers. (eg: 1 + 1 + 1)

#### Edit1: the boxes of the equation are empty right now

#### Edit 2:

That's my first post here and I didn't realize how fantastics your mind was, that's why my question was so broad. I'll accept the answer I was expecting but it doesn't mean that the other are wrong. Let's the upvoter decide.

Comment: Can you use other operators e.g. `(3-1) + (5*7) + ...`

Comment: And do you have to use all the numbers?

Comment: This puzzle is essentially "guess what trick I am thinking of". There are plenty of tricks/loopholes that could be used, and no real way to determine which one is "correct". https://xkcd.com/169/

Comment: I don't see any boxes.

Comment: @BenFrankel the boxes deflated to an underline as there's nothing holding it up.  Thomas should put '?' in it, or he can't do it for a reason =)

Comment: I think we need to know what kind of things there could be in a box? Because I can think of many possible answers that fit if we are allowed to use anything in the box... :)
For example:

[11] + [9] + [(15+15) / 3] = 30
in which:
(15 +15) / 3 = 30/3 = 10,
[...] is 1 box

Comment: Do any of the base-$x$ solutions answer the question to your satisfaction?

Comment: I got a perfect answer for this. I can add it, If this question can be reopened, .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> __+15+15 = 30

Assuming we don't need to use all the boxes

Comment: I think you have to fill in all the boxes as the question stated

Comment: Look at the comments under Alex's answer. Seems like maybe we can only use 2.

Comment: Yup that means you have to fill all the boxes...

Comment: Oh my mistake I read it wrong, how can I delete my answer

Comment: There should be an option to delete under your answer after your last line in the answer

Comment: @Alex I *never* said that you have to fill *all* the boxes :)

Comment: @Thomas a [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus_and_minus_signs#Plus_sign) quote: _The plus sign (+) is a binary operator that indicates addition, as in 2 + 3 = 5. It can also serve as a unary operator that leaves its operand unchanged (+x means the same as x)._ You can't have a plus sign alone.

Comment: I think "15+15+" isn't a valid mathematical expression, but I think "+15+15" would be.

Comment: @Qwerty I agree with Kevin comment even if yours is very pertinent. **But** I'll be more careful next time thanks to you

Comment: @Kevin Oh, _"+15+15"_ is completely legit. Silly me. pokerface _:|_

Answer (score 19):

To fully beat the "what about in other bases" dead horse,

> 1<sub>5</sub> + 11<sub>5</sub> + 13<sub>5</sub> == 1<sub>10</sub> + 6<sub>10</sub> + 8<sub>10</sub> == 15<sub>10</sub> == 30<sub>5</sub> 
>  3<sub>5</sub> + 11<sub>5</sub> + 11<sub>5</sub> == 3<sub>10</sub> + 6<sub>10</sub> + 6<sub>10</sub> == 15<sub>10</sub> == 30<sub>5</sub> 
>  1<sub>7</sub> + 11<sub>7</sub> + 15<sub>7</sub> == 1<sub>10</sub> + 8<sub>10</sub> + 12<sub>10</sub> == 21<sub>10</sub> == 30<sub>7</sub> 
>  1<sub>7</sub> + 13<sub>7</sub> + 13<sub>7</sub> == 1<sub>10</sub> + 10<sub>10</sub> + 10<sub>10</sub> == 21<sub>10</sub> == 30<sub>7</sub> 
>  3<sub>7</sub> + 11<sub>7</sub> + 13<sub>7</sub> == 3<sub>10</sub> + 8<sub>10</sub> + 10<sub>10</sub> == 21<sub>10</sub> == 30<sub>7</sub> 
>  5<sub>7</sub> + 11<sub>7</sub> + 11<sub>7</sub> == 5<sub>10</sub> + 8<sub>10</sub> + 8<sub>10</sub> == 21<sub>10</sub> == 30<sub>7</sub> 
>  1<sub>9</sub> + 13<sub>9</sub> + 15<sub>9</sub> == 1<sub>10</sub> + 12<sub>10</sub> + 14<sub>10</sub> == 27<sub>10</sub> == 30<sub>9</sub> 
>  3<sub>9</sub> + 11<sub>9</sub> + 15<sub>9</sub> == 3<sub>10</sub> + 10<sub>10</sub> + 14<sub>10</sub> == 27<sub>10</sub> == 30<sub>9</sub> 
>  3<sub>9</sub> + 13<sub>9</sub> + 13<sub>9</sub> == 3<sub>10</sub> + 12<sub>10</sub> + 12<sub>10</sub> == 27<sub>10</sub> == 30<sub>9</sub> 
>  5<sub>9</sub> + 11<sub>9</sub> + 13<sub>9</sub> == 5<sub>10</sub> + 10<sub>10</sub> + 12<sub>10</sub> == 27<sub>10</sub> == 30<sub>9</sub> 
>  7<sub>9</sub> + 11<sub>9</sub> + 11<sub>9</sub> == 7<sub>10</sub> + 10<sub>10</sub> + 10<sub>10</sub> == 27<sub>10</sub> == 30<sub>9</sub> 
>  1<sub>11</sub> + 15<sub>11</sub> + 15<sub>11</sub> == 1<sub>10</sub> + 16<sub>10</sub> + 16<sub>10</sub> == 33<sub>10</sub> == 30<sub>11</sub> 
>  3<sub>11</sub> + 13<sub>11</sub> + 15<sub>11</sub> == 3<sub>10</sub> + 14<sub>10</sub> + 16<sub>10</sub> == 33<sub>10</sub> == 30<sub>11</sub> 
>  5<sub>11</sub> + 11<sub>11</sub> + 15<sub>11</sub> == 5<sub>10</sub> + 12<sub>10</sub> + 16<sub>10</sub> == 33<sub>10</sub> == 30<sub>11</sub> 
>  5<sub>11</sub> + 13<sub>11</sub> + 13<sub>11</sub> == 5<sub>10</sub> + 14<sub>10</sub> + 14<sub>10</sub> == 33<sub>10</sub> == 30<sub>11</sub> 
>  7<sub>11</sub> + 11<sub>11</sub> + 13<sub>11</sub> == 7<sub>10</sub> + 12<sub>10</sub> + 14<sub>10</sub> == 33<sub>10</sub> == 30<sub>11</sub> 
>  9<sub>11</sub> + 11<sub>11</sub> + 11<sub>11</sub> == 9<sub>10</sub> + 12<sub>10</sub> + 12<sub>10</sub> == 33<sub>10</sub> == 30<sub>11</sub> 
>  3<sub>13</sub> + 15<sub>13</sub> + 15<sub>13</sub> == 3<sub>10</sub> + 18<sub>10</sub> + 18<sub>10</sub> == 39<sub>10</sub> == 30<sub>13</sub> 
>  5<sub>13</sub> + 13<sub>13</sub> + 15<sub>13</sub> == 5<sub>10</sub> + 16<sub>10</sub> + 18<sub>10</sub> == 39<sub>10</sub> == 30<sub>13</sub> 
>  7<sub>13</sub> + 11<sub>13</sub> + 15<sub>13</sub> == 7<sub>10</sub> + 14<sub>10</sub> + 18<sub>10</sub> == 39<sub>10</sub> == 30<sub>13</sub> 
>  7<sub>13</sub> + 13<sub>13</sub> + 13<sub>13</sub> == 7<sub>10</sub> + 16<sub>10</sub> + 16<sub>10</sub> == 39<sub>10</sub> == 30<sub>13</sub> 
>  9<sub>13</sub> + 11<sub>13</sub> + 13<sub>13</sub> == 9<sub>10</sub> + 14<sub>10</sub> + 16<sub>10</sub> == 39<sub>10</sub> == 30<sub>13</sub> 
>  5<sub>15</sub> + 15<sub>15</sub> + 15<sub>15</sub> == 5<sub>10</sub> + 20<sub>10</sub> + 20<sub>10</sub> == 45<sub>10</sub> == 30<sub>15</sub> 
>  7<sub>15</sub> + 13<sub>15</sub> + 15<sub>15</sub> == 7<sub>10</sub> + 18<sub>10</sub> + 20<sub>10</sub> == 45<sub>10</sub> == 30<sub>15</sub> 
>  9<sub>15</sub> + 11<sub>15</sub> + 15<sub>15</sub> == 9<sub>10</sub> + 16<sub>10</sub> + 20<sub>10</sub> == 45<sub>10</sub> == 30<sub>15</sub> 
>  9<sub>15</sub> + 13<sub>15</sub> + 13<sub>15</sub> == 9<sub>10</sub> + 18<sub>10</sub> + 18<sub>10</sub> == 45<sub>10</sub> == 30<sub>15</sub> 
>  7<sub>17</sub> + 15<sub>17</sub> + 15<sub>17</sub> == 7<sub>10</sub> + 22<sub>10</sub> + 22<sub>10</sub> == 51<sub>10</sub> == 30<sub>17</sub> 
>  9<sub>17</sub> + 13<sub>17</sub> + 15<sub>17</sub> == 9<sub>10</sub> + 20<sub>10</sub> + 22<sub>10</sub> == 51<sub>10</sub> == 30<sub>17</sub> 
>  9<sub>19</sub> + 15<sub>19</sub> + 15<sub>19</sub> == 9<sub>10</sub> + 24<sub>10</sub> + 24<sub>10</sub> == 57<sub>10</sub> == 30<sub>19</sub>

---

Edit: a cool idea from Ian MacDonald.

> A better answer would only use bases that match the allowed numbers ;)

> 11<sub>3</sub> + 11<sub>5</sub> + 15<sub>15</sub> == 4 + 6 + 20 == 30 
>  11<sub>3</sub> + 11<sub>7</sub> + 13<sub>15</sub> == 4 + 8 + 18 == 30 
>  11<sub>3</sub> + 11<sub>7</sub> + 15<sub>13</sub> == 4 + 8 + 18 == 30 
>  11<sub>3</sub> + 11<sub>9</sub> + 11<sub>15</sub> == 4 + 10 + 16 == 30 
>  11<sub>3</sub> + 11<sub>9</sub> + 13<sub>13</sub> == 4 + 10 + 16 == 30 
>  11<sub>3</sub> + 11<sub>9</sub> + 15<sub>11</sub> == 4 + 10 + 16 == 30 
>  11<sub>3</sub> + 11<sub>11</sub> + 11<sub>13</sub> == 4 + 12 + 14 == 30 
>  11<sub>3</sub> + 11<sub>11</sub> + 13<sub>11</sub> == 4 + 12 + 14 == 30 
>  11<sub>3</sub> + 11<sub>11</sub> + 15<sub>9</sub> == 4 + 12 + 14 == 30 
>  11<sub>3</sub> + 11<sub>13</sub> + 13<sub>9</sub> == 4 + 14 + 12 == 30 
>  11<sub>3</sub> + 11<sub>13</sub> + 15<sub>7</sub> == 4 + 14 + 12 == 30 
>  11<sub>3</sub> + 11<sub>15</sub> + 13<sub>7</sub> == 4 + 16 + 10 == 30 
>  11<sub>3</sub> + 13<sub>5</sub> + 13<sub>15</sub> == 4 + 8 + 18 == 30 
>  11<sub>3</sub> + 13<sub>5</sub> + 15<sub>13</sub> == 4 + 8 + 18 == 30 
>  11<sub>3</sub> + 13<sub>7</sub> + 13<sub>13</sub> == 4 + 10 + 16 == 30 
>  11<sub>3</sub> + 13<sub>7</sub> + 15<sub>11</sub> == 4 + 10 + 16 == 30 
>  11<sub>3</sub> + 13<sub>9</sub> + 13<sub>11</sub> == 4 + 12 + 14 == 30 
>  11<sub>3</sub> + 13<sub>9</sub> + 15<sub>9</sub> == 4 + 12 + 14 == 30 
>  11<sub>3</sub> + 13<sub>11</sub> + 15<sub>7</sub> == 4 + 14 + 12 == 30 
>  11<sub>3</sub> + 15<sub>7</sub> + 15<sub>9</sub> == 4 + 12 + 14 == 30 
>  11<sub>5</sub> + 11<sub>5</sub> + 13<sub>15</sub> == 6 + 6 + 18 == 30 
>  11<sub>5</sub> + 11<sub>5</sub> + 15<sub>13</sub> == 6 + 6 + 18 == 30 
>  11<sub>5</sub> + 11<sub>7</sub> + 11<sub>15</sub> == 6 + 8 + 16 == 30 
>  11<sub>5</sub> + 11<sub>7</sub> + 13<sub>13</sub> == 6 + 8 + 16 == 30 
>  11<sub>5</sub> + 11<sub>7</sub> + 15<sub>11</sub> == 6 + 8 + 16 == 30 
>  11<sub>5</sub> + 11<sub>9</sub> + 11<sub>13</sub> == 6 + 10 + 14 == 30 
>  11<sub>5</sub> + 11<sub>9</sub> + 13<sub>11</sub> == 6 + 10 + 14 == 30 
>  11<sub>5</sub> + 11<sub>9</sub> + 15<sub>9</sub> == 6 + 10 + 14 == 30 
>  11<sub>5</sub> + 11<sub>11</sub> + 11<sub>11</sub> == 6 + 12 + 12 == 30 
>  11<sub>5</sub> + 11<sub>11</sub> + 13<sub>9</sub> == 6 + 12 + 12 == 30 
>  11<sub>5</sub> + 11<sub>11</sub> + 15<sub>7</sub> == 6 + 12 + 12 == 30 
>  11<sub>5</sub> + 11<sub>13</sub> + 13<sub>7</sub> == 6 + 14 + 10 == 30 
>  11<sub>5</sub> + 11<sub>15</sub> + 13<sub>5</sub> == 6 + 16 + 8 == 30 
>  11<sub>5</sub> + 13<sub>5</sub> + 13<sub>13</sub> == 6 + 8 + 16 == 30 
>  11<sub>5</sub> + 13<sub>5</sub> + 15<sub>11</sub> == 6 + 8 + 16 == 30 
>  11<sub>5</sub> + 13<sub>7</sub> + 13<sub>11</sub> == 6 + 10 + 14 == 30 
>  11<sub>5</sub> + 13<sub>7</sub> + 15<sub>9</sub> == 6 + 10 + 14 == 30 
>  11<sub>5</sub> + 13<sub>9</sub> + 13<sub>9</sub> == 6 + 12 + 12 == 30 
>  11<sub>5</sub> + 13<sub>9</sub> + 15<sub>7</sub> == 6 + 12 + 12 == 30 
>  11<sub>5</sub> + 15<sub>7</sub> + 15<sub>7</sub> == 6 + 12 + 12 == 30 
>  11<sub>7</sub> + 11<sub>7</sub> + 11<sub>13</sub> == 8 + 8 + 14 == 30 
>  11<sub>7</sub> + 11<sub>7</sub> + 13<sub>11</sub> == 8 + 8 + 14 == 30 
>  11<sub>7</sub> + 11<sub>7</sub> + 15<sub>9</sub> == 8 + 8 + 14 == 30 
>  11<sub>7</sub> + 11<sub>9</sub> + 11<sub>11</sub> == 8 + 10 + 12 == 30 
>  11<sub>7</sub> + 11<sub>9</sub> + 13<sub>9</sub> == 8 + 10 + 12 == 30 
>  11<sub>7</sub> + 11<sub>9</sub> + 15<sub>7</sub> == 8 + 10 + 12 == 30 
>  11<sub>7</sub> + 11<sub>11</sub> + 13<sub>7</sub> == 8 + 12 + 10 == 30 
>  11<sub>7</sub> + 11<sub>13</sub> + 13<sub>5</sub> == 8 + 14 + 8 == 30 
>  11<sub>7</sub> + 13<sub>5</sub> + 13<sub>11</sub> == 8 + 8 + 14 == 30 
>  11<sub>7</sub> + 13<sub>5</sub> + 15<sub>9</sub> == 8 + 8 + 14 == 30 
>  11<sub>7</sub> + 13<sub>7</sub> + 13<sub>9</sub> == 8 + 10 + 12 == 30 
>  11<sub>7</sub> + 13<sub>7</sub> + 15<sub>7</sub> == 8 + 10 + 12 == 30 
>  11<sub>9</sub> + 11<sub>9</sub> + 11<sub>9</sub> == 10 + 10 + 10 == 30 
>  11<sub>9</sub> + 11<sub>9</sub> + 13<sub>7</sub> == 10 + 10 + 10 == 30 
>  11<sub>9</sub> + 11<sub>11</sub> + 13<sub>5</sub> == 10 + 12 + 8 == 30 
>  11<sub>9</sub> + 13<sub>5</sub> + 13<sub>9</sub> == 10 + 8 + 12 == 30 
>  11<sub>9</sub> + 13<sub>5</sub> + 15<sub>7</sub> == 10 + 8 + 12 == 30 
>  11<sub>9</sub> + 13<sub>7</sub> + 13<sub>7</sub> == 10 + 10 + 10 == 30 
>  11<sub>11</sub> + 13<sub>5</sub> + 13<sub>7</sub> == 12 + 8 + 10 == 30 
>  11<sub>13</sub> + 13<sub>5</sub> + 13<sub>5</sub> == 14 + 8 + 8 == 30 
>  13<sub>5</sub> + 13<sub>5</sub> + 13<sub>11</sub> == 8 + 8 + 14 == 30 
>  13<sub>5</sub> + 13<sub>5</sub> + 15<sub>9</sub> == 8 + 8 + 14 == 30 
>  13<sub>5</sub> + 13<sub>7</sub> + 13<sub>9</sub> == 8 + 10 + 12 == 30 
>  13<sub>5</sub> + 13<sub>7</sub> + 15<sub>7</sub> == 8 + 10 + 12 == 30 
>  13<sub>7</sub> + 13<sub>7</sub> + 13<sub>7</sub> == 10 + 10 + 10 == 30

Plus many more if we also allow base ten on the LHS, ex. 11 + 11<sub>5</sub> + 13 == 11 + 6 + 13 == 30

Comment: Not only "beat," but kick, stomp, stamp, jump, crush, and spit. Nicely done!

Comment: A better answer would only use bases that match the allowed numbers. ;)

Comment: @IanMacDonald, ok, I've added those too :-) I think 30 should remain in base 10, though, since 1) there's no "box" on the right hand side where I could put a new base; and 2) If I listed all the solutions where 30 is in a different base, this answer would be a _lot_ longer.

Answer (score 13):

I think we can use a little trick:

> Just use 9 upside down: 11 + 6 + 13 = 30

Comment: Not what I expected but I can't say a firm no

Comment: @Thomas hah, but for real answer are we expected to use all the boxes or?

Comment: The answer to your question is in my question... :)

Answer (score 12):

I think the answer is

> The sum of 3 odd numbers will always be odd, so there is no answer that will yield an even number

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say. Well done!

Comment: But then it wouldn't be a puzzle then would it? :|

Answer (score 5):

I can solve this puzzle as a physicist:

> 15 + 15 + 1 = 30

I guess it's more reasonable to request a precise mathematical 30 however..

The only boxes I see are the ones around 1,...,15...
I can fill the boxes like so:
<kbd>10</kbd>, <kbd>10</kbd>, <kbd>10</kbd>, <kbd>10</kbd>, <kbd>10</kbd>, <kbd>10</kbd>, <kbd>10</kbd>, <kbd>10</kbd>.

And then the problem becomes trivial.

Answer (score 2):

> 13 + 15 + 1 = 30  in base 9.

This isn't formatted the way I want, I'll go learn how to do that properly and come back to edit later.

Comment: It doesn't... Or maybe I made a mistake but I find (9+4)+(9+6)+1 which is 29

Comment: @Thomas If you convert all to base-10, 13->12, 15->14, 1->1

Comment: The operands and result are all base 9.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is:

> 11+13+1=30 in base 5

That's valid if your numbers are in base-5 instead of base-10.
Note that the text doesn't specify the base of the equation.

Comment: 11+3+1 => 20 (in base 5) not 30

Comment: By my reckoning, 1 + 11 + 13 in base 5 equals 1 + 6 + 8 in base 10, which equals 15 in base 10, which equals 30 in base 5.

Comment: @Kevin I didn't see it that way :)

Comment: @Kevin yes, but the answer used 3, not 13

Comment: Oops :-) I need to work on my reading comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

I am aware that the word *equation* implies that *L* should be equal *R*, but what if...

> ..it is sufficient to "make the equation true" by filling the boxes? ..or do I need to make the equation correct as well?

My answer is

> 1 + 1 + 1

Comment: What's your definition for "true"?

Comment: @BenFrankel As the OP stated. Filled boxes make the equation true.