# Series Problem By Gpuzzles - I Have Doubt

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

gpuzzles.com is one of my favorite sites along with StackExchange, but can someone please elaborate on the answer?

Problem:
Can you solve the number series problem by replacing boxes with numbers 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15?
Note: You can also repeat the number.
? + ? + ? = 30

Answer provided by the site is:
11.3135 + 9.3115 + 9.375

My question is Why can't be the answer be like 
11 + 9 + 9  = 30

Am I missing something?

[Source](http://gpuzzles.com/mind-teasers/most-popular-number-series/?source=stackexchange)

Comment: Short answer... in real maths we have: 11+9+9=29.

Comment: Note that the OP specifically asks *why* a "normal" solution cannot work (which is answered [here](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/11732/25412) BTW).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to rehash,

> The sum of three odd numbers will always be odd, so you can't get to thirty using three of the numbers provided.

Though that doesn't explain

> Why the given answer isn't something simple like 11.5 + 9.5 + 9 = 30.

It occurs to me now that

> The question is likely asking you to use ALL the odd numbers between 1-15 to fill in the boxes

which is why the answer is so convoluted. In my opinion, the question is worded poorly if this is the case.